# 【.NetFramework4.0】コンテキストメニューの子アイテムがクリックされた事を検知したい

Tags: .net, vb.net

おはようございます。

表題の件につきましてご教示頂けますでしょうか？

VisualBasic(.NetFramework4.0),VisualStudio2010,Windows7(64Bit)で、コンテキストメニューの各項目を動的に生成して表示しています。

メニューの各項目の幾つかは更に子項目を持つ構造になっております。

この時項目が選択された事を検知するのにContextMenuStripのItemClickedイベントを試しているのですがこのイベントでは子項目のクリックが検知できないようです。

このような場合どのようにして全ての項目（親・子）のクリックを検知するのでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

`AddHandler`ステートメントを使って動的に生成するタイミングで`ToolStripMenuItem`にイベントハンドラーを追加すればよいです。

```
' Dim item As ToolStripMenuItem
AddHandler item.Click, AddressOf item_Click

…

Private Sub item_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
…
End Sub
```